# Where can I find a lot of good exercises on the wave equation?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, wave-equation

I find myself in the situation of needing to understand the wave equation inside and out -- I've studied it, obviously, and have been looking for resources for some time. So far in my search I'm surprised to learn that there does not seem to be a single good source for building up intuition and familiarity with this very important equation. Am I just looking in the wrong places? What resources would you suggest?

Comment: Any good book on partial differential equations will include quite a bit of material on the wave equation as well as the heat and Laplace equations as these three equations are fundamental to the theory of second order PDEs.

Comment: There's nothing wrong per se with asking about resources for self-study of a topic, but "a lot of good exercises" for a topic can be interpreted many ways.  Your Question doesn't give us Readers much insight into what you know about the wave equation, or what sort of *practice* you think you need.

Comment: You may want to look at 'Equations of Mathematical Physics' by Tikhonov and Samarskii.